# Why there are two different php.ini configuration files Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am wondernig why when I type `php --ini` in my terminal I find the output below

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path: `/etc/php/8.0/cli`
- Loaded Configuration File:         `/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`
- Scan for additional .ini files in: `/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d`

however when I run `phpinfo();` I find the output below

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path: `/etc/php/8.0/fpm`
- Loaded Configuration File:         `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini`

and the actual loaded file is this  `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini` anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Well, probably it was considered convenient to have different php configuration for cli and web usages